# Adding elements in DOM elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a question regarding adding elements in DOM dynamically. I am trying to a webpage that has an input field for entering email and when add email button is hit, email is added into HTML DOM. I have created the following code, but it has a couple of issues, firstly i want each email to appear in a newline and secondly since I am using clonenode() the input element as it is appears which doesnt look pleasing to eyes. Moreover, I am looking for a better way to achieve the same task. The first snippet is the javascript for inserting email ids into html dom dynamically and the second snippet is HTML code.

```js
<script>
 
  function insert()
  {
 
   var elem = document.createElement("email"); 
   var elmnt = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0];
      var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
         elem.appendChild(cln);
      var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
      var child = document.getElementById("edemo");
      element.insertBefore(elem,child);

  } 
 
 </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyleassign7-1.css"/>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
 </script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
 <h2> Inserting Elements in HTML DOM</h2>
 <p> Enter Email Id and hit Add Email button to insert Email in HTML DOM
 </p>
 <form id="myForm" >
 <label>E-mail : </label>   <input type="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail Here" name="em" autofocus><br>
   
 </form>
 <br>
 <br>
 <button onclick="insert()">Add Email!</button><br>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <email id="edemo"></email>
 </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want:

1. Have form with input and submit button
2. After pushing submit button -> add email to some div

You can do this:

```js
// Get element from dom
function get(name){
  return document.querySelector(name);
}
// When page elements are ready
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  // Get form
  get(".js-form").addEventListener("submit", function(){
    var email = get(".js-form_email").value;
    // Create container for email
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerText = email;
    get(".js-emails").appendChild(div);
    // clear field from text
    get(".js-form_email").value = "";
  });
}, false);
```

```html
<form class="js-form">
  <input type="text" class="js-form_email" placeholder="Enter email here">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<div class="js-emails">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function insert()
{
  var email= document.querySelector("[type=email]").value;
  
  if( !validateEmail(email) )
    return;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML= email;
  document.querySelector("#emailList").appendChild(li);

  document.querySelector("[type=email]").value= "";

}

function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

```css
#addEmail,#addEmail:focus{
  color: #009afd;
  font-weight:bold;
  border:none;
  background:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:20px;
  outline:0;
}

#emailList li{
  list-style:none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #aaa;
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyleassign7-1.css"/>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
 </script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
 <h2> Inserting Elements in HTML DOM</h2>
 <p> Enter Email Id and hit Add Email button to insert Email in HTML DOM
 </p>
    <ul id="emailList">
       
    </ul>
 <form id="myForm" >
   <label>E-mail : </label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail Here" name="em" required autofocus>             
      <button id="addEmail" onclick="insert()">+</button><br>
   
 </form>
 <div id="mydiv">
 <email id="edemo"></email>
 </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```